# HTML/PHP How do I generate new text-fields on a form based upon a select option field value?

Tags: php, html, forms

When the user picks either phone or email I want the form to then generate a box to enter the details of which they selected. How do I do this? Thanks.

```
<div class="field-container full clearfix">
        <label class="required">What is your prefered method of contact?    </label>
        <select name="fields[contact]">
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <option value="phone">Phone</option>
            <option value="email">E-mail</option>
        </select>
    </div>


<div class="field-container full clearfix">
        <label class="required">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="fields[phone]" value="<?=  (isset($fields['phone']) ? $fields['phone'] : '' )?>"/>
        </div>



 <div class="field-container full clearfix">
    <label class="required">E-mail Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="fields[email]" value="<?=   (isset($fields['email']) ? $fields['email'] : '' )?>"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: yous should do this with js . make `display:none;` below fields and make visible with choosing select-box

Comment: I just made something like this yesterday for someone, give me a few minutes and I'll post it.

Comment: Revealing is different than generating. Do you want something free-form? Or something where you just reveal additional fields?

Comment: Either generating or revealing would work I guess

Comment: I've edited my answer @codevalue. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Sounds good @Jordan Davis

Comment: @michael Thats exactly what I want. Where do I put the Javascript?

Comment: Best is to put it in an external file and include it to your html file, wait one second, I'll edit my answer for you @codevalue

Comment: Added it @codevalue, if you have further questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet that shows you how to do that with javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('selection').addEventListener('change',function(){
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.hideAndShowInput > input');
  for (var i = 0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
    inputs[i].setAttribute('type','hidden');  
    inputs[i].parentNode.style.display= 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById(this.value).parentNode.style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(this.value).setAttribute('type',this.value);
  
});
```

```html
<div class="field-container full clearfix">
        <label class="required">What is your prefered method of contact?    </label>
        <select id="selection" name="fields[contact]">
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <option value="phone">Phone</option>
            <option value="email">E-mail</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 


<div class="field-container full clearfix hideAndShowInput" style="display:none;">
        <label class="required">Phone</label>
        <input type="hidden" id="phone" name="fields[phone]" value="">
        </div>



 <div class="field-container full clearfix hideAndShowInput"  style="display:none;">
    <label class="required">E-mail Address</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="email" name="fields[email]" value=""/>
    </div>

<div class="field-container full clearfix">
        <label class="required">otherField1</label>
        <input type="text" id="other" name="fields[p]" value="otherField">
        </div>



 <div class="field-container full clearfix">
    <label class="required">otherField2</label>
    <input type="text" id="lsd" name="fields[em]" value="otherField2"/>
    </div>
```

Please note that I added a Id to the `select` element and to the input elements.

### EDIT | USAGE

Create a file, call it script.js or whatever you like and put this in it:

```
    document.getElementById('selection').addEventListener('change',function(){
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.hideAndShowInput > input');
  for (var i = 0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
    inputs[i].setAttribute('type','hidden');  
    inputs[i].parentNode.style.display= 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById(this.value).parentNode.style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(this.value).setAttribute('type',this.value);

});
```

Save the file to a folder on your server that is accesible. For example /public/js/script.js

In your html, add

```
<script src="/public/js/script.js"></script> <!-- or however your path is -->
```

to the very end of your file, directly before the closing `</body>` tag So that it looks like this

```
 <div class="field-container full clearfix">
        <label class="required">What is your prefered method of contact?    </label>
        <select id="selection" name="fields[contact]">
            <option value="blank"></option>
            <option value="phone">Phone</option>
            <option value="email">E-mail</option>
        </select>
    </div>



<div class="field-container full clearfix hideAndShowInput" style="display:none;">
        <label class="required">Phone</label>
        <input type="hidden" id="phone" name="fields[phone]" value="">
        </div>



 <div class="field-container full clearfix hideAndShowInput"  style="display:none;">
    <label class="required">E-mail Address</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="email" name="fields[email]" value=""/>
    </div>

<div class="field-container full clearfix">
        <label class="required">otherField1</label>
        <input type="text" id="other" name="fields[p]" value="otherField">
        </div>



 <div class="field-container full clearfix">
    <label class="required">otherField2</label>
    <input type="text" id="lsd" name="fields[em]" value="otherField2"/>
    </div>
<script src="/public/js/script.js"></script>  <!-- here is the script included -->
</body>
```

That's it.

Comment: This works great, however when I choose an option I lose some of the above form textboxes

Comment: Upon load it looks like this : http://puu.sh/jnZno/50882745b0.png When I choose an option it looks like this : http://puu.sh/jnZuC/1ba5d5955d.png

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know that you have further inputs on the page, wait a second pleases

Comment: Can you please have a look at the snippet, now it only affects those two inputs @codevalue

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. @michael

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick... let me know?

//CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.field-hide{
    display: none;
}   
</style>
<script>
function valChange(ele){
    var fields = document.getElementById("container").children;
    for(var i=0; i < fields.length; i++){
        fields[i].classList.add("field-hide");
    }
    switch(ele.value){
        case "phone":
            document.getElementById("phone").classList.remove("field-hide");
            break;
        case "email":
            document.getElementById("email").classList.remove("field-hide");
            break;
    }
}           
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="field-container full clearfix">
        <label class="required">What is your preferred method of contact?</label>
        <select type="text" name="fields[contact]" onchange="valChange(this)">
            <option value="blank" selected disabled>Choose</option>
            <option value="phone">Quoted</option>
            <option value="email">Labour Only</option>
         </select>    
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="field-container full clearfix field-hide" id="phone">
            <label class="required">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="fields[phone]" placeholder="enter phone number">
        </div>
        <div class="field-container full clearfix field-hide" id="email">
            <label class="required">E-mail Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="fields[email]" placeholder="enter email">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Add an id to your select: select name="fields[contact]" id="contact"
2. Set phone and email fields to hidden by using a class or inline style: div class="field-container full clearfix hide-this" id="phone-container"
   --or just set style: display:none;
3. Javascript:

   ```
   $('#contact').change(function(){
   if(this.selectedOptions[0].text == 'phone') {
       $('#phone-container').show().focus();
   }else{$('#phone-container').hide();}
   });
   ```